# How to fire a keypress event on a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a firstName and a lastName input that I am hiding and replacing with a single fullName input box. I am then using JqueryUI autocomplete on the dynamically created input and it works fine. When I try to write unit tests for this and dynamically add some input and fire the 'keydown' event, the box with the autocomplete results does not show up (I want to assert that I'm getting the desired results in my tests). 
If I type "s" in the input manually, the results show up just fine. 
I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8j3fgxL/5/) that shows my problem.

HTML:

```
<input id="firstName">
<input id="lastName">
```

JQuery:

```
// add the single input
$('#firstName').before('<input id="fullName">');
// remove the original first and last name fields
$('#firstName, #lastName').hide();
// call autocomplete on the dynamically created input
$("#fullName").autocomplete({
  source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "ASP", "Basic", "ColdFusion", "Haskell", "JavsScript", "Lisp", "Scala", "Scheme"]
});

// ** start unit test **

// auto populate the dynamic input
$('#fullName').val('sc');
// force a keypress to show the autocomplete options
$('#fullName').trigger('keypress');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#fullName').trigger('keypress');
```

with

```
$('#fullName').autocomplete('search');
```

**Update**

OP would prefer not to use the widget's API, and common events such as `keydown` and `keypress` depend on `event.keyCode` which is not present when `trigger` is invoked.

Interestingly, `input` event doesn't suppress key press. So this may be ideal for OP's unit testing.

```
$('#fullName').trigger('input')
```

Comment: This works great, but is there another way to do this without calling autocomplete so I can use this in my unit test?

Comment: You could try `.trigger('input')`